# How can I get around Webpack errors when building Azure SDK for node.js

Tags: webpack

I am using the Azure SDK for node.js https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node

Any suggestions as to how I can get around all these errors when I build with webpack?

thanks!

```
ERROR in ./~/tough-cookie/package.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\tough-cookie\package.json Line 2: Unexpected toke
n :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "_args": [
|     [
|       "tough-cookie@~2.2.0",
 @ ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 38:14-40

ERROR in ./~/ms-rest/~/mime-db/db.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\ms-rest\node_modules\mime-db\db.json Line 2: Unex
pected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "application/1d-interleaved-parityfec": {
|     "source": "iana"
|   },
 @ ./~/ms-rest/~/mime-db/index.js 11:17-37

ERROR in ./~/mime-db/db.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\mime-db\db.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "application/1d-interleaved-parityfec": {
|     "source": "iana"
|   },
 @ ./~/mime-db/index.js 11:17-37

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/cache.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\cache.json Line 2: Unex
pected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "properties": {
|     "beforeRequest": {
|       "$ref": "#cacheEntry"
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 4:9-32

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/cacheEntry.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\cacheEntry.json Line 2:
 Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "oneOf": [{
|     "type": "object",
|     "optional": true,
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 5:14-42

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/content.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\content.json Line 2: Un
expected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "size",
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 6:11-36

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/entry.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\entry.json Line 2: Unex
pected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "optional": true,
|   "required": [
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 9:9-32

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/cookie.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\cookie.json Line 2: Une
xpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "name",
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 7:10-34

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/page.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\page.json Line 2: Unexp
ected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "optional": true,
|   "required": [
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 12:8-30

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/creator.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\creator.json Line 2: Un
expected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "name",
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 8:11-36

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/log.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\log.json Line 2: Unexpe
cted token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "version",
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 11:7-28

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/pageTimings.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\pageTimings.json Line 2
: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "properties": {
|     "onContentLoad": {
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 13:15-44

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/postData.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\postData.json Line 2: U
nexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "optional": true,
|   "required": [
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 14:12-38

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/record.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\record.json Line 2: Une
xpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "name",
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 15:10-34

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/response.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\response.json Line 2: U
nexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "status",
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 17:12-38

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/har.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\har.json Line 2: Unexpe
cted token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "log"
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 10:7-28

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/request.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\request.json Line 2: Un
expected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "type": "object",
|   "required": [
|     "method",
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 16:11-36

ERROR in ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/timings.json
Module parse failed: C:\Users\blah\devel\nextshot\node_modules\har-validator\lib\schemas\timings.json Line 2: Un
expected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "required": [
|     "send",
|     "wait",
 @ ./~/har-validator/lib/schemas/index.js 18:11-36
```

Comment: Hi, I'm very pleasure for help, but your question is not clear for using Azure SDK for node,js and webpack. What do you want to do? How did you get the issue?

Comment: obviously, you need a file-loader in your webpack config that handles .json-files